# Data Sheet Interpretation - "Insulation Area" and mystery Symbol

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, datasheet

While creating a (my first) device package for [this](http://www.attend.com.tw/product_view.php?id=56) Micro SD socket in CadSoft EAGLE
I stumbled over the inclusion of an "insulation area" in the recommended pcb layout:

[image: recommended layout]

I'm guessing this is supposed to prevent the contact springs from contacting any tracks under the socket. There are holes on the bottom through which this could conceivably happen.

- Am I right in my assumption?
- Is there something I should do to the layout in that area or will the solder resist suffice?
- What does the Symbol in the green box mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I right in my assumption?

The distance between the main contacts and outline of the contacts within the INSULATED is 2.7mm. The maximum pad length on a microSD is 1.6mm.

By specifying an area that must have resist, the chances of shorting is minimised

[image]

> Is there something I should do to the layout in that area or will the
>   solder resist suffice?

Resist should be fine but check tolerance stack up.

> What does the Symbol in the green box mean?

That symbol is a mechanical drafting symbol for positional tolerance

> 3.4 LOCATION
>    - Position tolerances are the most common location tolerance. Concentricity and symmetry are also types of location tolerances. Profile tolerances can be used to control location, but these are covered separately.
>   [image]
>   3.4.1 Position -The position tolerance symbol is a circle with a horizontal and vertical line drawn through the circle. See Figure 26.
>
> [source: [Drafting manual. Dimensioning and Tolerancing Symbols.](http://www.draftingzone.com/shoppingzone/6-1.pdf)]

Comment: I thought he was querying the symbol in the green box?

Comment: Missed that bit of the question. I think both were being asked about.